# Ajax is not defined - Grails jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails

I'm using jQuery in my project by the jQuery and jQuery-ui plugins. I have a simple form which I want to submit in Ajax call to the controller. The thing is, when I put the `<g:submitToRemote />` tag and then click it, firebug shows error that `Ajax is not defined`. What can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this line to the layout file that your form GSP is using

```
<g:javascript library="jquery" plugin="jquery"/>
```

and the following to your `grails-app/conf/Config.groovy`

```
grails.views.javascript.library="jquery"
```

### Grails 2.0.0

In Grails 2.0.0 the correct way to include JQuery is to use the new resources plugin by adding the following to the layout GSP

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- These 2 lines include JQuery -->
        <g:javascript library="jquery"/>
        <r:layoutResources/>

        <g:layoutHead/>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: My project was missing config file line.

Answer (score 2):

you can also add `<g:setProvider library="jquery"/>` on the view needed